# Typeahead Bloodhound doesn't filter remote dataset

Tags: typeahead.js

I'm trying to use Typeahead/Bloodhound in a simple HTML application sourcing from a small database of about 1000 records of names. I want to fetch the subset of names beginning with the first letter (last, first) which should be the only fetch needed and the displayed suggestions should then filter down as further letters are typed in.

So, for example the letter G is being used in the examples below. I have further updated my code for use with real typed in names, but my problem is as follows.

Example 1: If I just prefetch as shown, then all works fine:

```js
  var players = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('NAM'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    prefetch: '/json.php?dat=players&qry=G'
  });
```

The first 5 names pop up and as I type more of the name, the list filters down properly. Ok, but not dynamic with the correct name set.

I could live with a prefetch of the entire database, but that doesn't seem to work either. No data fetch is done or some limit is being reached.

Example 2: Next step is to move this to remote:

```js
  var players = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('NAM'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: {
      url: '/json.php?dat=players&qry=G'
    }
  });
```

This works for the first letter but no further filtering is being performed. The suggestion list does not change and is not narrowed down. There seems to be nothing displayed beyond the first 5 entries regardless of what I type.

Example 3: In the end, I want to use something like this:

```js
  var players = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('NAM'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: {
      url: '/json.php?dat=players&qry=',
      prepare: function(query, settings) {
        settings.url += query.substr(0, 1);
        return settings;
      }
    },
    limit: 100
  });
```

This approach still doesn't work even though I submit the complete query string every time and every letter a new remote fetch is done. (This doesn't seem right and much more network traffic than I want.) The suggestion list shortens down, but rapidly becomes smaller than 5 entries and is not supplemented by other data in the returned name set json.

Example 1 is available at http://acblunit391.org/test1.php 
Example 2 is available at http://acblunit391.org/test2.php 
Example 3 is available at http://acblunit391.org/test3.php

Using 0.11.1 and appropriate jquery 1.10.2 that seemed to work.